# Integration of schema registry

Tags: json, apache-kafka, event-handling, confluent-schema-registry

I am developing an application(B) which uses Schema Registry and allows clients(A) to send data to any other platform(C). General design:
Client A -> Platform B -> Destination C

So I am not necessarily publishing messages to kafka.

1. Is there any documentation on how to integrate and use Schema registry with a custom application which is not publishing to kafka? All the documentation I could find is around using registry with kafka.
2. For this setup, I am finding it difficult to finalize the serialization format to use- if I use avro/protobuf, it requires a corresponding class/message in application B. This means clients will need to update B every time a new schema is added or an old one updated. For JSON, such a class should not be needed (I guess?) since it is schemaless.

Comment: Unclear if you actually **need** a schema **registry**, vs just "have a schema". I.e. You can use OpenAPI or Protobuf (gRPC) to define schemas between services.

Comment: I want to use Schema Registry because it can take care of compatible schema evolution, and also ensure that messages adhere to the defined schema. I want to use it with Couchbase primarily. Client A currently writes to CB directly, and I want to add a layer in b/w to ensure schema adherence.

Comment: Sure, but if you use the options I mentioned, then messages also will adhere to a schema and there are other methods to ensure schema evolution compatibility

Answer (score 0):

What is the intended schema format for your solution? If a binary structured format, then serializing key/value (Java Objects - > byte Array), you definitely need a Schema Registry integrated in your application.

Refer : https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/index.html

Again for #2, Schema Registry provides you a better Schema Management capability in terms of Schema Evolution and compatibility checks, so you need not to worry much about updating your KAFKA Clients whenever a schema evolves.

Answer (score 0):

> All the documentation I could find is around using registry with kafka

Because the Confluent Registry stores schemas in a Kafka topic. So, you'll therefore need a Kafka installation, even if it is not used by your services. Note: There are other Schema Registry implementations.

> finding it difficult to finalize the serialization format to use

Doesn't really matter; the Confluent Registry also supports [defining your own](https://yokota.blog/2020/02/26/playing-chess-with-confluent-schema-registry/). What actually matters is how supported that format is within your clients. E.g. Avro support in Golang or .NET isn't the greatest.

> requires a corresponding class/message in application B. This means clients will need to update B every time a new schema is added or an old one updated

So? Do you never upgrade other 3rd party libraries for new methods/fixes? Why would you treat your schemas any different?

The Registry enforces backwards compatible changes, by default. Schema upgrades aren't required unless you actually need the new data being sent.

> For JSON, such a class should not be needed (I guess?) since it is schemaless

The Confluent Schema Registry uses JSONSchema, so it is not schemaless.

Kafka itself supports a form of JSON in the Connect API that has a schema, but it is not integrated with any Registry, and as such cannot guarantee any schema evolution rules.

> any documentation on how to integrate and use Schema registry with a custom application which is not publishing to kafka

You'd use the [REST API directly](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/develop/api.html).

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your questions:

1. Documentation in [Schema Registry API Reference](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/develop/api.html#sr-api-reference). Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73188700/how-to-create-avro-schemas-key-value-before-the-topic-in-confluent-schema-regi) how to add key/value schemas for Platform B.
2. Once the key/value schemas are setup in the Schema Registry, then you have to configure the connector properties to serialize/deserialize the message.

Connector properties to serialize/deserialize avro messages.
(Connector sink example)

```
   {
      
      "name": "eraseme_connector_schema_test_v01",

      "config": {

        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",

        "tasks.max": "1",

        "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",

        "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",

        "topics": "eraseme_topic_schema_test_v05",

        "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxxx.xxxx",

        "connection.user": "USER",

        "connection.password": "PASSOWRD",

        "insert.mode": "upsert",

        "delete.enabled": "true",

        "pk.mode": "record_key",

        "pk.fields": "YOUR_KEY_1, YOUR_KEY_1,...,YOUR_KEY_N",

        "auto.create": "true",

        "auto.evolve": "true",

        "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",

        "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081"

      }

    }
```

Comment: I am not using any kafka connector. C is couchbase. Currently A publishes to C directly, I just want to add a layer B which ensures documents written to couchbase adhere to a schema.

Comment: @agyeya I'd strongly recommend using the Couchbase connector https://docs.couchbase.com/kafka-connector/current/sink-configuration-options.html The connector framework integrates nicely with the Registry